# Spring security Namespaces

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security

I am new to Spring Security, and while going through the official documentation for Spring security 3.1.x https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/session-mgmt.html

In `12.3 Concurrency Control` It is mentioned that `In addition, you will need to add the ConcurrentSessionFilter to your FilterChainProxy. The ConcurrentSessionFilter requires two properties, sessionRegistry, which generally points to an instance of SessionRegistryImpl, and expiredUrl, which points to the page to display when a session has expired`

My doubt is that whether adding the name-space `<concurrency-control>`  will meet this requirement or do I need to explicitly add the beans specified for achieving concurrency ?

Any help is much appreciated.